# RTNETLINK answers: Argument list too long

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I backported mcp251xfd CAN driver for v4.9
I can see now `can0` in `ifconfig` but when I do:

```auto
$ sudo ip link set can0 type can bitrate 125000
$ sudo ip link set up can0
```

I get the following:
`RTNETLINK answers: Argument list too long`

It comes from the second command.

Comment: The second command should be `sudo ip link set can0 up`.

Comment: @IanAbbott ok, but same error.. Also tried with ifconfig

Comment: Find where you are doing `return -E2BIG;` somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to comment out the check here: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.9.170/source/drivers/base/regmap/regmap.c#L1730

These lines:

```auto
if (map->max_raw_write && map->max_raw_write < val_len)
        return -E2BIG;
```

I saw that there no such check in newer kernel versions.